# MVC5 Use multiple model on view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a login system that record every time that users login on my website.

I'm using MVC template that gives me a login system.

I had my 'Activity log' working. On the view it shows the data I had on Model, so, I needed to display more data, that were on Users table.

To do that I followed the 3rd answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319488/how-do-i-display-data-from-multiple-tables-in-a-single-mvc-view) question.

Because I created the model that contains info about others 2 Models (user and activity), the system have created this table on database too (it's empty).

There are some bad pratices here? It's normal, in this situation, the system create the table?

Another question, I do querys on controller, I'm doing it right?

ActivityLogViewModels.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace AccountSystem.Models
{
    public class ActivityLogModels
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string userID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Acess { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityLogViewData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int accessID { get; set; }
        public string userID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Acess { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

}
```

ActivityLogController.cs

```
using System;
...


namespace AccountSystem.Controllers
{
    public class ActivityLogController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: ActivityLog
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<ActivityLogViewData> model = null;
            List<ActivityLogViewData> verify = new List<ActivityLogViewData>();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("xxx");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", connection);
            command.CommandText = "select dbo.AspNetUsers.Email,dbo.AspNetUsers.UserName,dbo.ActivityLogModels.ID,dbo.ActivityLogModels.Acess,dbo.AspNetUsers.Id from dbo.ActivityLogModels inner join dbo.AspNetUsers on dbo.ActivityLogModels.userID=dbo.AspNetUsers.Id";
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                    verify.Add(new ActivityLogViewData { Email = dr[0].ToString(), UserName = dr[1].ToString(), accessID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString()), Acess = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[3].ToString()), userID = dr[4].ToString()});

            }
            connection.Close();
            //return View(db.ActivityLog.ToList());
            return View(verify);
        }
```

The Page (Create, Edit, Details and delete don't work after my changes)

[image]

Table empty
[image]

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? I see you declared a dbContext but you're writing queries by hand. I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, I'm using EF. I tried to work with the dbContect but I could not :/ Thats was the only way I could do that

Comment: I`ll recommend this tutorial for getting you up to speed with EF. I understand you're mixing concepts and getting lost in the middle of it. With EF you don't need to write queries like that. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx