# Add and edit data from multiple table in a single MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to edit and add data from multiple tables. 
I started as said in this solution:
[How do I display data from multiple tables in a single MVC view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319488/how-do-i-display-data-from-multiple-tables-in-a-single-mvc-view)

I had 3 models: uzytkownik, rolaPowiazanie and rola. Between "uzytkownik" and "rolaPowiazanie" is connection "idUzytkownik", between "rolaPowiazanie" and "rola" - "rolaId". I'd like to show in a table information from "uzytkownik" and "rola".

```
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nazwaRoli)
        </th>
(...)
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nazwaRoli)
    </td>
(...)
```

DisplayNameFor gives "nazwaRoli" but DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nazwaRoli) gives "idRola". When I want to see in the view items from idRola, there was idRola too.

I add this into controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<UzytkownicyRola> model = null;
        List<UzytkownicyRola> verify = new List<UzytkownicyRola>();

        var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AplikacjaContext"].ConnectionString;

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            cn.Open();

            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string query = "select  uzytkownik.idUzytkownik,uzytkownik.imie,uzytkownik.nazwisko,uzytkownik.pesel,uzytkownik.haslo,uzytkownik.email,rolaPowiazanie.idUzytkownik,rolaPowiazanie.idRola,rola.idRola,rola.nazwaRoli from uzytkownik inner join rolaPowiazanie on uzytkownik.idUzytkownik=rolaPowiazanie.idUzytkownik inner join rola on rolaPowiazanie.idRola=rola.idRola;";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    verify.Add(new UzytkownicyRola { idUzytkownik = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()), imie = dr[1].ToString(), nazwisko = dr[2].ToString(), pesel = dr[3].ToString(), haslo = dr[4].ToString(), email = dr[5].ToString(), idRolaPowiazanie = Convert.ToInt32(dr[6].ToString()), idRola = Convert.ToInt32(dr[7].ToString()), nazwaRoli = dr[8].ToString() });
                }
            }

            cn.Close();
            return View(verify);
        }
    }
```

And in the view, when I want to show "nazwaRoli" i get "idRola". What should I change to correct show "nazwaRoli"?

Automatically generated Edit look's like:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        UzytkownicyRola uzytkownicyRola = db.UzytkownicyRolas.Find(id);
        if (uzytkownicyRola == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(uzytkownicyRola);
    }
```

--EDIT--
I also have got a problem with Edit and Details.

There's an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.UzytkownicyRolas'.

Error source:

> UzytkownicyRola uzytkownicyRola = db.UzytkownicyRolas.Find(id);

"UzytkownicyRolas" exist only in AplikacjaContext (DbContext created by me earlier) and this is in DAL folder.
 How can I change this to this method works?

AplikacjaContext'c code:

```
public partial class AplikacjaContext : DbContext
{
    public AplikacjaContext()
        : base("name=AplikacjaContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<rola> rola { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<rolaPowiazanie> rolaPowiazanie { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<uzytkownik> uzytkownik { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Aplikacja.Models.UzytkownicyRola> UzytkownicyRolas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @CzarnePaski, whaz the error? Could you provide View and the detail of db.UzytkownicyRolas.Find(). And maybe check if that if the index of "nazwaRoli" is given wrong with the one of "rolaId" when reading data row.

Answer (score 0):

#### When I want to show "nazwaRoli" i get "idRola". What should I change to correct show "nazwaRoli"?

The ordinal number: 8 on dr (:SqlDataReader) will get "idRola" in your sql.

```
select  
uzytkownik.idUzytkownik,--0
uzytkownik.imie,--1
uzytkownik.nazwisko,--2
uzytkownik.pesel,--3
uzytkownik.haslo,--4
uzytkownik.email,--5
rolaPowiazanie.idUzytkownik,--6
rolaPowiazanie.idRola,--7
rola.idRola,--8
rola.nazwaRoli --9
...
```

Using column name on SqlDataReader will be more readable, like this...

```
nazwaRoli = dr["nazwaRoli"].ToString();
```

---

#### The type or namespace name 'UzytkownicyRola' does not exist

Please check that you have the right reference on the class : "UzytkownicyRola", the error is not on "UzytkownicyRola**s**"

Comment: Thank you very much. You're advices helped me and now Index view and Create view works as I want. I had also problem, with "UzytkownicyRolas", I don't chack closely and I thouhgt for a minute, that everywhere (in Create, Edit and Details) there's the same problem.

Comment: Be sure that the table: "dbo.UzytkownicyRolas", is exist in the target database  and with the right scheme name: "dbo".  Cus the error: " Invalid object name 'dbo.UzytkownicyRolas'" means the table could not be found in your database. After these checks, could you post the code of  "AplikacjaContext"?

Comment: The AplikacjaContext class is correct, could you check that the table : 'dbo.UzytkownicyRolas' is exist in the database and the permission of the current login user in the connection string?

Comment: Can you explain me something? I don't get it. Why I should have table UzytkownicyRolas if I want my data in tables "dbo.uzytkownicy", "dbo.rola" and "dbo.rolaPowiazanie"? And I'd like to write Edit and Details method, which operate on this three tables.

Comment: `UzytkownicyRola uzytkownicyRola = db.UzytkownicyRolas.Find(id)` will generate a sql query `SELECT TOP 2 * FROM UzytkownicyRolas WHERE id=XXX` and this sql will has the error " Invalid object name" if the table is not exist in the database. If object:UzytkownicyRola isnt what you expect for the viewModel of edit page, then you have to inquery the right table.